# iframe scroll bars and hide menu on website

Tags: html, css, iframe

[image]

```
<iframe src="https://website.com/index.php?/something/1"
    scrolling="no"
    frameborder="no"
    overflow="hidden"
    height=500px
    width=500px> </iframe>
```

I'm trying to use iframe to show a part of this website on my website. I have tried to look for an answer but couldn't find one. Although I have `scrolling="no"`, it still shows 2 scrollbars. How can I get rid of those?

Also, there is a menu on the website that stays while scrolling down and is covering the part I want to show. Is there a way to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this in your CSS file to get rid of the scroll panes:

```
iframe{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

As for your navigation menu appearing on inside the iframe cannot controlled by you. However you could try this solution as well but i'm not sure it'll work perfectly.

```
#content-to-hide{
    display:none;
}
```

**Update 1**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myframe").contents().find('#logo').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<iframe src="https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/" scrolling="no" style=" width: 550px; height: 700px; overflow:hidden" id="myframe"></iframe>
```

As i've tried to hide the element using above js code several SO members said the iframe source should support cross origin requests.

> Due to browser security, content cannot generally be accessed using or
>   manipulated from within an iframe unless it is on the same domain. 
>   This may not be the case with some older browsers, but definitely is
>   now.

This is regulated by the [Same-origin Policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy).

Also see this [article](http://www.dyn-web.com/tutorials/iframes/refs/iframe.php).

> Note: These cross-document interactions are only possible if the documents have the same origin.

**Update 2**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var css = '<style type="text/css">#logo{display: none!important;}</style>';
  $("#myframe").contents().find("head").append(css);
});
```

Trying to inject some css code also didn't do any effect at all.

Comment: I am trying to do this inside a html block. Added a <style> to that. and tried to hide overflow that way. Didn't change anything

Comment: I changed to chrome and the scrolling bars weren't there. weird. So that one is done. Still the menu problem is there. What should the #content-to-hide be?

Comment: Yes this is not a cross browser solution apparently. That is a long shot on hiding the content you want inside the iframe by its element or class id.

Comment: What would you suggest? I need to have the Website showing on that website without the menu.

Comment: Yes, i'm working on a solution now. I'll post an update as soon as i'm done. :)

Comment: I've tried to hide an element which is inside the iframe but sadly it doesn't support manipulating that. you could also search stackoverflow about this but most of the members said this doesn't work since cross domain security issues and such.

Comment: Damn. Well i have no idea what to do then. The element i am trying to hide is header.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy says "content cannot generally be accessed using or manipulated from within an iframe unless it is on the same domain"

Comment: well. could i create a white bar that hides the menu?

Comment: of course you can. It will be a fix for your solution but make sure that compatibles with responsive layout of the website. :)

Comment: well i have to do something to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

I were able to hide the header using
    margin-top: -100px;
To hide the menu